# What is the largest number of identical satellites launched together?

Tags: payload, satellite-constellation

What is the largest number of (essentially) identical satellites launched together?

- Form factor alone (e.g. 1U, 3U cubesat) is not enough to make satellites identical, they need to be the same design, purpose, function, etc.; in other words, *essentially identical.*
- Thus this is a different question than [Highest number of satellites launched on a single rocket](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1059/12102) because those can be any mix of different satellites.
- For the purposes of this question, the satellites also need to be active in some way. A bunch of "[needles](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13340/what-was-the-first-practical-use-of-a-satellite-constellation#comment34854_13340)" or "[marbles](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21891/12102)" wouldn't count.
- If the answer is going to be 60 or less, better hurry up and answer before Wednesday!

---

Teslarati.com [says](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-starlink-satellites-tease-revolutionary-design/):

> The mission is currently scheduled to launch at 10:30 pm EDT (02:30 UTC), May 15th

Elon Musk [tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1127388838362378241) about an upcoming launch, that hasn't happened yet at the time this question is posted.

> First 60 @SpaceX Starlink satellites loaded into Falcon fairing. Tight fit.

[image: First 60 @SpaceX Starlink satellites loaded into Falcon fairing. Tight fit.]

Comment: When did this launch get delayed to?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn this is the tweet from May 16, I haven't heard anything more but I don't follow that closely. I think they are doing some serious software updates on the satellites while they sit inside the fairing, just to show off!  https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1129181397262843906

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thursday has now been [tweeted](https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1130500331698364418).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### 88!

[PSLV-C37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSLV-C37) launched 88 identical satellites into a sun-synchronous orbit. These satellites were for an imaging company called "Planet Labs". Technically the only ones that were identical were the CubeSats (Which were named Doves) but they were launching 4 other types of satellites from this launch too.

> The rocket launched Cartosat-2D, a few other satellites and 88 nanosatellites: two from
>   India, one each from Kazakhstan, Israel, the Netherlands, Switzerland,
>   and the United Arab Emirates, along with 88 from the United States of
>   America – 88 Dove satellites and 8 LEMUR satellites.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjt16.png) The three
>   Indian satellites launched were Cartosat-2D, INS-1A, and INS-1B.[12]
>   Arrangements for the launch of the 104 satellites were made between
>   ISRO's commercial arm Antrix Corporation Limited, under the auspices
>   of the Indian Government's Department of Space, and the international
>   customers.

In addition to this, it mentions that Planet Labs has 143 total Doves in operation.

> Among the 96 satellites belonging to US companies, 88 CubeSats were
>   owned by Planet Labs, a private Earth imaging company based in San
>   Francisco, California.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhokR.jpg) Weighing roughly 5 kilograms (11 lb) each,
>   the satellites separated from the rocket in different directions to
>   avoid collision.[15] With the launch of PSLV-C37, Planet Labs
>   increased its fleet of satellites to 143, which is the largest private
>   satellite fleet in operation.

Some more specific information on the [Dove 3u cubesat can be found here](https://www.satimagingcorp.com/satellite-sensors/other-satellite-sensors/dove-3m/). Most notably, the following was mentioned in the list of things about it:

> Dove satellite constellation holds the world record of the most
>   satellites launched at once from one rocket and will collect imagery
>   up to 2 million km² per day. The Dove satellite constellation is a
>   fleet of nanosatellites deployed from the International Space Station
>   to take images of Earth. The satellite constellation is operated by
>   Planet Labs Inc., 88 nanosatellites called Doves weighing only 11
>   pounds each, provides 3 meter multispectral image resolution for a
>   variety of mapping applications including several humanitarian and
>   environmental applications, from monitoring deforestation and
>   urbanization to improving natural disaster relief and agricultural
>   yields around the world.

Deployed image of one:

[image]

A bunch of them sitting in their stowed state:

[image]

So it would seem the answer for max number is 88 and will not be affected by Wednesday.

(Unless someone else finds a different example).

Comment: 88! okay so this record is safe for a little while longer. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh It's the most I could find, but as you know I'm by no means an Almanac for space facts ;).

Answer (score 14):

### 480,000,000!<sup>†</sup>

<sup>†</sup>Depending on how you define satellite.

I think [Project West Ford](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_West_Ford) is the current record holder, with 480,000,000 individual satellites.

Well technically 480,000,000 copper dipole antennas, designed to act as an artificial ionosphere.

Here is a photo of a few of the dipoles:

[image: Project West Ford, antennas compared to a stamp for scale]

Comment: @DarcyThomas Obligatory nitpick: the word you're looking for is "caveat".

Comment: I saw that after. Although this answer is unlikely to be accepted, I think it is a good 'caveat answer'

Comment: @duskwuff Thanks, I thought it looked off.

Comment: It would really suck to become a pincushion for all of these microharpoons. Did all of their orbits decay by now or is it still in effect?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Have a look at the Wikipedia page, I think most of the properly dispersed ones may have, but there are still clumps of the the botched deployments. If those pins caused a hull or suit breach, it would really really suck! (oh god, I am so sorry...)