# What is the first time that two satellites were launched together as the same payload?

Tags: launch, artificial-satellite, history, spaceflight-firsts

Below I've assembled some research into the question of which launch is actually the first to carry two satellites into orbit, but so far I think the results are inconclusive. So despite there being *discussion* of this in other posts, I think this issue of history and records in Space Exploration *still needs its own, definitive answer.*

**Question:** What is the first time that two satellites were launched together as the same payload?

---

**Background/research:**

The first launch that I could find it is this:

[22 June 1960 - Thor Ablestar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Thor_and_Delta_launches_(1960%E2%80%931969)#1960)

- Transit 2A
- GRAB-1

but maybe there are other launches before that?

Failed launches also count

Related questions:

- similar but not specifically a duplicate- [History of multiple-payload launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36303)
- [Highest number of satellites launched on a single rocket](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/highest-number-of-satellites-launched-on-a-single-rocket)

Comment: Near-duplicate: [History of multiple-payload launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36303/195)

Comment: `+1` I think that this is a good and well-researched question and I've made an edit to differentiate it from previous questions in hopes that it can receive a definitive answer.

Comment: I found in the JSR launch database this - 1959 Apr 13 - Thor Agena A - Discoverer 2 and SRV - successful launch, but I can't find what SRV is

Comment: SRV is the General Electric Satellite Return Vehicle, which returns the film capsule from a Keyhole spy satellite. So, I would count this as a component of the satellite, not a separate second satellite.

Comment: A dummy mass simulator SOLRAD was successfully launched on 13 April 1960, attached to Transit 1B, proving the dual satellite launch technique - rocket: Thor Ablestar - Though it does't mention of they actually separated and orbited as two separate satellites

Comment: Vanguard SLV-5 launched on 14 April 1959 - failed to launch two satellites. This one seems to be the first attempt - Vanguard SLV-5 hoped to put into orbit two satellites: the Vanguard 3A satellite, a magnetometer, and a 76 cm (30 in) round inflatable sphere with an air density measurement device - looks like 3 satellites though, I'm confused

Comment: @JoeJobs considering that they were given two distinct satellite numbers (S00031 and S00033), separation seems likely.